# Possible to load content only when its scrolled to first time?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm a frontend dev with no windows phone dev experience trying to put together some mockups for a Win phone app.

Essentially the app has a feed and 2 forms ; a post form ( to post to this feed) and a feedback form (for app feedback). I was thinking of doing something similar to other mobile apps I've used on Android, whereby the user can swipe left/right to switch between the feed and the forms and I would like the app the content on demand rather than loading everything when the app first loads up in a hope to improve performance.

1. Is this possible i..e to do this loading on demand
2. Is there any references I can refer to when documenting my design? e.g. an example app or the key functions that would be required to do this sort of "on demand" loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement the two views in a [Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot%28VS.92%29.aspx#), the content will be loaded when the user accesses it for the first time and will also give you the left/right swipe you are describing. As a point of reference, the system settings screen is a pivot.

Alternatively, you could look at the [DeferredLoadContentControl](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/200927/Windows-Phone-7-DeferredLoadContentControl) which does something similar in the name of perceived performance.

Comment: I was under the impression that even `Pivot` controls loads everything at startup (if used out the box). Although it's easy, you have to manually implement `on-demand` loading. See second bullet point of `Best Practices`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941101%28v=vs.92%29.aspx